# Outputting all text file titles to a textbox on Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, search, text

Getting a bit stuck on a piece of code I'm trying to write and was hoping for a helping hand if anyone knows where I'm going wrong!

I have a simple Windows Form where I have a folder browser. The user will browse to a folder and any sub-folders within will then be searched for a text file that has the word "Passed" in the title (not the body of the text file itself). There will be files with "Passed" in from many different folders, and I want the functionality of the app to search through all sub-folders and return the all the files that have this in their name.

At present I have the following code:

```
    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a path");
        }
        else
        {
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*Passed*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string name = resultsText.Text;
            foreach(string file in allFiles)
            {
                if (file.Contains("Passed"))
                {
                    resultsText.Text = file;
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

However, in the resultsText texbox, it only returns 1 value. There are multiple files with "Passed" in their title and I would like to print them all to this textbox. Does anyone know where I may be going wrong and why I am only getting one file rather than all of them?

Also, this method seems to return the whole file path e.g.)
C:\Program Files\Test\abc\PassedTests.txt - does anyone know how I can trim the full path so it just returns the file name and extension?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `resultsText.Text = file` you overwrite it each time. Try `resultsText.Text += file + Environment.NewLine`. Also, if you're looking for `"*Passed*.*"` the second check `if (file.Contains("Passed"))` *should* be unnecessary.

Comment: And you should probably check if the entered path is valid, or you'll get an exception. `var dir = textBox1.Text; if (Directory.Exists(dir)) { resultsText.Text = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*Passed*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, file) => current + file + Environment.NewLine); } else { MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid path"); }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the text. At the moment, you're overwriting the previous value by using `resultsText.Text = file;`.

```
 if (file.Contains("Passed"))
 {
    resultsText.AppendText(file);
 }
```

What may be more performant would to use build your string using a `StringBuilder` and then assign that to the TextBox.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string file in allFiles)
{
  if (file.Contains("Passed"))
  {
     sb.Append(file);
  }
}

resultsText.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 1 line of code:

```
resultsText.Text = file;
```

To this:

```
resultsText.Text += file;
```

The + will append the text and not overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer for your second question.
try this to get only the file name
`Path.GetFileName(filepath)`